# Authorization failed when trying to download blob via CDN - Works locally

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, cdn

I am trying to download blobs through my CDN endpoint. When I run my API locally on localhost everything works fine. But once I publish my app so it runs as an app service on Azure. I get the error message "Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header i formed correctly..."

When I run the api on app service but remove the CDN endpoint and run on the normal blob storage URI it works too without error message.

Any ideas of what could be wrong?

**The error message:**
Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:xxx
Time:2022-12-22T12:45:13.3900743Z
Status: 403 (Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.)
ErrorCode: AuthenticationFailed

Additional Information:
AuthenticationErrorDetail: The MAC signature found in the HTTP request 'xx' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign: 'GET

bytes=0-8388607
x-ms-client-request-id:xxxx
x-ms-date:Thu, 22 Dec 2022 12:45:13 GMT
x-ms-range:bytes=0-268435455
x-ms-return-client-request-id:true
x-ms-version:2021-08-06
/xx/stagecontainer/18'.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that it's a CORS problem. It's really hard to try to help without an error message or seeing some screenshot, but that's where I would start checking:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-cors

Comment: Thank you! I looked into it and added a new CDN endpoint and called it straight from my API instead of the localhost, so that it wouldnt cache the response from localhost. But it still doesn't work. I updated my answer with the errormessage